# Angular 2 ngClass with user-supplied strings

Tags: angular

I am trying to append a dynamic, user-supplied class string to a component, using `ngClass`. I get no syntax error warning in IDE, but Angular compiler complains about the syntax (`Missing expected : at column...`):

```
<li [ngClass]="{[item['class']]: true}">{{ item.title }} </li>
```

An item has a structure as in

```
interface IItem {
  'class': string;
  title: string;
}
```

So what is wrong with my ngClass input?

Comment: what's the `item` in your template ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<li [ngClass]="item['class']">{{ item.title }} </li>
```

or :

```
<li [ngClass]="getClass(item)">{{ item.title }} </li>
```

component :

```
getClass(item){
     // calculation 
     return 'my-class'
  }
```

Comment: Well, sort of... this prevents me from using any other calculated classes here.

Comment: Then use `<li [ngClass]="{ item['class']: true }">{{ item.title }} </li>` or `<li [ngClass]="[ item['class'] ]">{{ item.title }} </li>`

Comment: the key of the object must be static not dynamic